# segfault on free() a pointer to char*

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I have a problem with `free()` function when I allocate memory using `malloc()`.

When the program runs, it generates a segmentation fault. And I generate a coredump of the program. When I use gdb, it shows segfault in the call to free().

This my code:

```
char * temp_filename;
temp_filename = (char *) malloc(50);
temp_filename = strrchr(package->_local_filename, '/');
strcat(package->_cache_filename, temp_filename);
free(temp_filename);
```

I am unable to figure out my mistake. Does anyone help me to find my mistake?
**Thanks**
**Sorry For the erros on code, now is OK**

Comment: You don't use `temp_filename` anywhere between the malloc and the free. Are you sure that is all your relevant code?

Comment: Also, are you sure the segfault isn't happening on the line before? `strcat` can segfault when `package->cache_filename` isn't pointing to enough allocated memory for itself plus the length of `temp_filename_dest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite your allocated pointer with a pointer into some other string that you are searching:

```
temp_filename = (char *) malloc(50);
temp_filename = strrchr(package->_local_filename, '/');
```

And then, you free that pointer erroneously, because it is no longer a pointer returned by `malloc()`:

```
free(temp_filename);
```

To fix, remove the code that allocates and frees.

```
char * temp_filename;
temp_filename = strrchr(package->_local_filename, '/');
strcat(package->_cache_filename, temp_filename);
```

Comment: And I can't deallocate the memory used by "temp_filename"?

Comment: @VitorLuis: You have already overwritten the pointer value after the `strrchr()` call, thus you were never using that memory. So, you can just not call `malloc()` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `temp_filename` does not point to memory allocated using `malloc()`. Instead, it contains a pointer into `package->_local_filename`:

```
temp_filename = strrchr(package->_local_filename, '/');
```

You can remove the calls to `malloc()` and `free()` since they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strncat instead of strcat, and make sure you are not overflowing the end of your allocated buffer.